# Comparing two DataTables (Unit Testing, Integration Testing, C#, TestMethod)

Tags: c#, unit-testing, datatable, integration-testing, assert

What kind of tests should be carried out in unit testing when comparing Datatables that are supposed to be different and have multiple rows.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void ExecuteOutWithMultipleDataTables()
    {
        //Arrange
        int id1 = TestOrderBuilder.New().Build();
        DataTable dtDefault = CreateDefaultDataTable(id1, "OUT", "TableDesc", DateTime.Now);

        //Act
        object[] result = OracleDatabase.ExecuteOut(SqlStatements.Cursor, procedureParameters);
        DataTable dtResults = result[0] as DataTable;

        //Assert
        Assert.IsNotNull(dtDefault);
        Assert.IsNotNull(dtResults);
        Assert.AreNotEqual(dtDefault, dtResults);
        Assert.AreNotSame(dtDefault.Rows[0][0], dtResults.Rows[0][0]);
        Assert.AreNotSame(dtDefault.Rows[0][1], dtResults.Rows[0][1]);
    }
```

This is an example of some of what I have wrote already, but I am unsure if I am on the right track.

Does anyone have advice?

Mac

Comment: is it a unit test ? i doubt , looks like integration test

Comment: Sorry, yes I think it is Integration testing to a certain extent. dtDefault is just a made up default Datatable which does not matter but dtResults is pulled from the database (but is also of basic default values that do not matter too much).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to write a helper method if you need to verify each row and column value.

Also , it does not looks like an unit test because it looks you are calling real database rather then mocking it.

may be something like below

```
private bool IsTableSame(DataTable t1, DataTable t2)
    {
        if (t1 == null)
            return false;
        if (t2 == null)
            return false;
        if (t1.Rows.Count != t2.Rows.Count)
            return false;

        if (t1.Columns.Count != t2.Columns.Count)
            return false;

        if (t1.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Any(dc => !t2.Columns.Contains(dc.ColumnName)))
        {
            return false;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i <= t1.Rows.Count-1; i++)
        {
            if (t1.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Any(dc1 => t1.Rows[i][dc1.ColumnName].ToString() != t2.Rows[i][dc1.ColumnName].ToString()))
            {
                return false;
            } 
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: How do you write a helper method?
Yes it is integration testing, not so much Unit Testing.

Comment: That Looks fantastic, but what does this line do?
    if (t1.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Any(dc => !t2.Columns.Contains(dc.ColumnName)))

What is DC?

Comment: Thank you for sharing this. In addition, I would recommend using asserts within the method that provide meaningful messages when they fail. This will make it easier to troubleshoot a failing unit test.

Answer (score 5):

I have wrapped the same helper method above to use asserts. It helps in debugging a unit test.

```
private void AssertTableRecordsAreEqual(DataTable expectedTable, DataTable actualTable)
    {
        Assert.IsNotNull(actualTable, "Table is empty");
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedTable.Columns.Count, actualTable.Columns.Count, "Number of columns in actual and expected tables are different");
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedTable.Rows.Count, actualTable.Rows.Count, "Number of records in actual and expected tables are different");
        Assert.IsFalse(expectedTable.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Any(dc => !actualTable.Columns.Contains(dc.ColumnName)), "Table column names are different");

        for (int i = 0; i <= expectedTable.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            Assert.IsFalse(expectedTable.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Any(dc1 => expectedTable.Rows[i][dc1.ColumnName].ToString() != actualTable.Rows[i][dc1.ColumnName].ToString()), "Table row value is different");
        }
    }
```